# Time difference betweet two days issue

Tags: android, date, datetime, time

I use this code to get time difference in seconds between 10 December 2013 and now:

```
        Time time_countdown = new Time();
        time_countdown.set(10, 12, 2013);
        Time time_now = new Time();
        time_now.setToNow();

        int constSecond = 1;
        int constMinute = 60 * constSecond;
        int constHour = 60 * constMinute;
        int constDay = 24 * constHour;

        long timeDifferense = time_countdown.toMillis(true) - time_now.toMillis(true);
        int secondsDifferense = (int)(timeDifferense / 1000);
```

but the differense is wrong

Comment: Please let us know *how* the difference is wrong.  It will make it much easier to answer your question if we know what is going wrong.

Comment: number of days is 73 and that is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Month is 0-based.  That is, it counts from 0 to 11, where 11 is December.  Try switching your line to `time_countdown.set(10, 11, 2013)`.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html